# Angular ng-repeat shows nothing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a list using ng-repeat. When used directly in html it works without issues. However, when I try to insert the same code using directive, the ng-repeat does nothing and does not show even one item.

What I tried:

- I used the same html in both .html and .js files - in html works without issues, in directive no
- I added `<h1>Say Something</h1>` just to check if the directive is applied correctly - yes, it is
- I tried declaring the array directly in the directive (the values should be passed through scope) - no change in behaviour
- `alert(Appraisals[0].id)` shows pop-up with correct information
- checked for spelling and typos but everything seems correct...

The .js file:

```
var app = angular.module('AngularDirectiveDemo', []);
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('AngularDirectiveDemo');
    app.directive('scSchedule', function () {
        //alert($scope.Appraisals[0]);
        var Appraisals = [
            { id: 2432, name: "Greatness" },
            { id: 2486, name: "Mediocrity" }
        ];
        alert(Appraisals[0].id);
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<div>'+
                 '<h1>Say Something Directive</h1><ul> <li ng-repeat="x in Appraisals">' +
                 '{{x.id}}<a href="#" ng-click="viewAppraisalDetails(x)">Details</a></li></ul><div>blanko</div></div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.viewAppraisalDetails = function (appraisalToView) {

                    console.log('viewing details for ' + appraisalToView.Id);

            }
        }

        };
    });

    angular.module('AngularDirectiveDemo').controller('scheduleCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.Appraisals=[
            {id: 2432, name:"Greatness"},
            {id:2486, name:"Mediocrity"}
        ];
    });

}());
```

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="AngularDirectiveDemo">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script> -->
    <script src="../Codes/SampleDirective.js"></script>

    <title>Angular Directive Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="scheduleCtrl">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in Appraisals">{{x.id}}   {{x.name}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <sc-Schedule></sc-Schedule>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Replace `sc-Schedule` by `sc-schedule`

Comment: Also, your directive is out of the `<div ng-controller="scheduleCtrl">`, so Appraisals is not in its scope.

Comment: Thank you. The second comment solved the issue. Could you post it as an answer so that I could accept it? Also, why didn't it help when I declared Appraisals inside the directive?

Comment: Because it still wasn't in the scope. It was just a local variable of the directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created local variable Appraisals so the view doesn't see it. It needs to be in a scope:

```
alert(Appraisals[0].id);
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
       Appraisals: '='
    }
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
      scope.Appraisals = Appraisals;
    },
    template: '<div>'+
```